# SQL UPDATE with Multiple ANDs

Tags: sql, sql-update, sql-server-2012

I'm receiving the error

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'location'

when running this query:

```
UPDATE dbo.table 
SET name = 'Matt' 
WHERE date = '2013-11-23' 
  AND time = '12:57' 
  AND location = 'London'
```

If I modify the query to remove any one of the ANDs the query works.

Two questions:

1. Is it not possible to have more than one `AND` in the `WHERE` condition for an `UPDATE`?
2. How do I structure the query to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: Seems to work fine... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dbee9/1 ...although it would give that exact result if you didn't include `= 'London'` when you run the query.

Comment: Works fine on 2012. No problem with the column names. There must have been a typo in your actual code you haven't shown us. As well as suggestion by @JoachimIsaksson typing a random character between `AND` and `location` would generate that error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be the use of reserved words like time and date. Try putting [] around those names and see if it works. And more importantly, you should use better names for your columns instead of those reserved words.